# VS Code moves cursor to beginning of file on Save As

Tags: visual-studio-code

When using VS Code, anytime I use Save As, the cursor will jump to the beginning of the file.  This is undesired if I am trying to create many new files and only changing 1 small line or variable.  Sublime and Atom keep the cursor in the same spot when performing a Save As.  Is there anyway to keep the cursor in the same location on a Save As?  I have tried disabling all extensions and currently am not trimming trailing whitespace

Comment: Set a bookmark and return to the spot via F2.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesnt work.  I would guess because the save as treats the file as a new file and clears the bookmarks